# U-SQL Column Type Convertion

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have created a U-SQL query, which gets the input file from the DataLake Store and converts the values. The final output is stored in DataLake Store.

```
DECLARE @in string = "system/dbotable{*}.tsv";
DECLARE @out string ="system/temp.tsv";

@searchlog =
    EXTRACT 
        Id         int,
        Address    string,
        number     int
    FROM @in
    USING Extractors.Tsv();

@transactions =
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM @searchlog;

@result =
    SELECT 
        Id ,
        Address,
        number 
    FROM @transactions
    WHERE RowNumber == 1;

OUTPUT @result
    TO @out
    USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

And it is showing the following error,

> Execution failed with error '1_SV1_Extract Error : '{"diagnosticCode":195887132,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"User","errorId":"E_RUNTIME_USER_EXTRACT_COLUMN_CONVERSION_INVALID_ERROR","message":"Invalid character when attempting to convert column data.","description":"HEX: \"2243616E696E6522\" Invalid character when converting input record.\nPosition: line 1, column index: 1, column name: \"Id\".","resolution":"Check the input for errors or use \"silent\" switch to ignore over(under)-sized rows in the input.\nConsider that ignoring \"invalid\" rows may influence job results and that types have to be nullable for conversion errors to be ignored.","helpLink":""

Comment: Does the input file have headers that need to be skipped?  Can you show some sample data please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the Id column is *not always of type Integer*.

I would extract the Id column as string first and then in a second step, try to convert it to Int, using a user defined function as shown in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621309.aspx (example based on DateTime).

The other option, would be to use `silent:true` in your extractor, so you automatically ignore rows which fail the conversion.